# Why is my Log4j logging not displaying to the console?

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, log4j, slf4j

I have a web app built in Eclipse/STS with Spring MVC and Maven.

I want to add logging, so I added SLF4 and Log4J to the pom.xml like this ..

```
     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I have a simple log4j.properties file in the `project/src/main/resources` folder, like this ...

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I created a Logger class in my main WebController, like this ...

```
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebController.class);
```

And in my "showMain" method I'm doing some logging stuff, like this ...

```
@RequestMapping(value={"", "/", "showhome"}, method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
public ModelAndView showHome(Model model) {

    logger.info("########### TEST LOG INFO");
    logger.error("########### TEST LOG ERROR");
    logger.warn("########### TEST LOG WARN");
    logger.debug("########### TEST LOG DEBUG");

    /* ... */
}
```

But when I run the application, I don't see any logging output in the console.

I also don't see anything in the console output to indicate that it is even using the logging framework.  And there's no "can't find log4j.properties" message or anything.

I tried putting the log4j.properties in different places in the project, but nothing.

I must be missing something simple?  What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated that you added log4j in your pom.xml but I do not see it, are you sure this is your newest version of pom.xml?

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That's what was missing!  Thanks.  I incorrectly assumed that <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId> was enough.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help, just FYI, I posted another Log4j question, if you could take a look that would be great!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62094862/why-is-there-log4j-output-to-the-console-from-other-code-but-not-from-my-code

Comment: Sorry man, I was out for a couple of days, I checked, glad you found an answer in your second question. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

In your pom.xml is missing the logging engine, you could use log4j2.
Please Consider to use the latest version of [log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html) instead of log4j (1.2.x) because you could take advance of:

1. Lazy log: log4j(1.2.x) build a string also if a level is not activated
2. lambda in order to avoid evaluation of expensive methods
3. A lot of appenders for modern platform
4. More easy way to configure a lot of parameters (reload configuration, appenders, ...)

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: You are right, but I got a similar answer from another user so I marked theirs correct first.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Elliot.Easton.2020 This is a better answer though.  The latest version of `log4j` (1.2.17) is from May 2012.  There's no reason not to use a maintained version that is updated with modern tools.