# Why is there Log4j output to the console from other code, but not from my code?

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, log4j, slf4j

I have a web app built with Eclipse/STS and Spring MVC.

I'm using slf4j and log4j for logging.

Here's my log4j.properties file ... I know it's being used because I added the text "MY TEST PROPS FILE" to the date pattern and it appears in the logs ...

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=MY TEST PROPS FILE - %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

When I run my web app, the console output looks like this ... you can see the "MY TEST PROPS FILE" in the output ...

```
MY TEST PROPS FILE - 2020-05-29 17:18:36 DEBUG BasicResourcePool:422 - decremented pending_acquires: 0
MY TEST PROPS FILE - 2020-05-29 17:18:36 DEBUG BasicResourcePool:1644 - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@468f3122 [managed: 3, unused: 2, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@642b4cb2)
MY TEST PROPS FILE - 2020-05-29 17:18:36 DEBUG NewProxyConnection:1260 - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@71cf92cb: close() called more than once.
MY TEST PROPS FILE - 2020-05-29 17:18:36 DEBUG BasicResourcePool:1644 - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@468f3122 [managed: 3, unused: 2, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@642b4cb2)
MY TEST PROPS FILE - 2020-05-29 17:18:36 DEBUG BasicResourcePool:1644 - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@468f3122 [managed: 3, unused: 2, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@642b4cb2)
```

My problem is, the logging I attempt from my code doesn't appear in the console output.

I'm doing this ...

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/* ... */

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebController.class);

/* ... */

    @RequestMapping(value={"", "/", "showhome"}, method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
    public ModelAndView showHome(Model model) {

        logger.info("########### TEST LOG INFO");
        logger.error("########### TEST LOG ERROR");
        logger.warn("########### TEST LOG WARN");
        logger.debug("########### TEST LOG DEBUG");

/* ... */
    }
```

I must be missing something simple.  Why are my test logger calls not appearing in the Console output?

UPDATE - SOLUTION FOUND: I found a solution and posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my issue.

I changed to log4j2 by putting this in my pom.xml ...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

And then I created a log4j2.properties file like this ...

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

filters = threshold

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appenders = console

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Works now.

Cheers, all.